# Hide action bar in Android

Tags: android, xml

I am making a android app with android studio with a login at the first site. The problem is that the action bar should be hidden on the login activity but shown on the main activity after the user logged in. Is there a way to do this? I just found tutorials how I can remove it permanently.

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Add these lines:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 0);
```

For example:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loguin);
```

And probably you will need to change your extension class.
I guess you have this:

```
 public class Loguin extends AppCompatActivity
```

Just change AppCompatActivity. **ONLY IF YOU NEED IT**

```
 public class Loguin extends Activity
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Login activity replace android:theme line in androidmanifest like below

```
<activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" // <<== this
>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Hide Action bar from Activity**

```
<activity 
android:name=".LoginActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

No need to add android:theme, it will automatically show you full screen.
Add one line to onCreate() method.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 0);
```

Thanks

Comment: OP asked about the action bar, not the status bar.